# Uso do hashmap para fazer comparações

Tags: java, hashmap

Tenho a seguinte situação: recebo uma lista de `itensVenda`, e nela eu tenho associado a `Venda`. Na `Venda` eu tenho uma list de `itensVenda` e o `Cliente`, e no Cliente, eu tenho associado uma lista de Vendas.

Tenho que arrumar a hierarquia, e retornar uma lista de clientes.
Fiz o seguinte código(faltando o else), que "conserta" essa hierarquia, adicionando em um hashmap, para depois colocá-lo em uma list de clientes.

```
public class HierarquiaImpl implements Hierarquia {
@Override
public Collection<Cliente> montarHierarquia(Collection<ItemVenda> itens) {
    Collection<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    Map<Cliente,Integer> clientesMap = new HashMap<Cliente,Integer>();
    for (ItemVenda itemVenda : itens) {
        if(!clientesMap.containsKey(itemVenda.getVenda().getCliente())) {
            List<ItemVenda> itensVendas = new ArrayList<ItemVenda>();
            List<Venda> vendas = new ArrayList<Venda>();
            itensVendas.add(itemVenda);
            itemVenda.getVenda().setItems(itensVendas);
            vendas.add(itemVenda.getVenda());
            itemVenda.getVenda().getCliente().setVendas(vendas);
            Cliente cliente = itemVenda.getVenda().getCliente();
            Integer idCliente = itemVenda.getVenda().getCliente().getId();
            clientesMap.put(cliente, idCliente);
            clientes.add(itemVenda.getVenda().getCliente());
        }
        else{
            if (clientesMap.get().equals())
        }
    }
    System.out.println("teste");
    return clientes;
}
```

O problema é que cada cliente pode ter várias vendas, cada venda pode ter vários itens, uma venda pertence a um cliente.

O código acima adiciona ao hashmap quando a mesma ainda não tem um cliente inserido. Se tiver um cliente, terá que pegar a venda associada ao itemVenda deste "`for`", comparar se é igual a alguma venda ja cadastrada no mesmo cliente, se sim, irei apenas inserir o item nessa venda. Se não, farei outra venda para o item.

Classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private List<Venda> vendas;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Venda> getVendas() {
        return vendas;
    }

    public void setVendas(List<Venda> vendas) {
        this.vendas = vendas;
    }

}
```

Classe ItemVenda:

```
public class ItemVenda {

    private int id;
    private Venda venda;
    private String codigoProduto;
    private int quantidade;
    private BigDecimal valor;

    public ItemVenda() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Venda getVenda() {
        return venda;
    }

    public void setVenda(Venda venda) {
        this.venda = venda;
    }

    public String getCodigoProduto() {
        return codigoProduto;
    }

    public void setCodigoProduto(String codigoProduto) {
        this.codigoProduto = codigoProduto;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

}
```

Classe Venda:

```
public class Venda {

    private int codigo;
    private LocalDateTime dataVenda;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private float valorTotal;
    private List<ItemVenda> items;

    public Venda() {
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDataVenda() {
        return dataVenda;
    }

    public void setDataVenda(LocalDateTime dataVenda) {
        this.dataVenda = dataVenda;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public float getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(float valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public List<ItemVenda> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ItemVenda> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi.. Qual é a treta?

Answer (score 0):

Se comparar dois objetos da forma acima, o que será comparado é o local do mesmo na memória e nesse caso só serão o mesmo objeto se apontarem para a mesma posição na memória.

Para resolver esse problema implemente os métodos **hashCode()** e **equals()** nas classes que deseja comparar.

Exemplo de implementação para a classe Cliente

```
 @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((vendas == null) ? 0 : vendas.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        if (vendas == null) {
            if (other.vendas != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!vendas.equals(other.vendas))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```